# How to call desktop notifications on Ubuntu GNOME?

Tags: gnome, notification

I was wondering how exactly one makes a desktop notification come up on Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18? What I mean is how do I get one of these desktop notifications to come up with text that I have specified?:

[image]

It would be useful if I could execute a command or script that could do this so that I would be able to get notified about things in my system.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In the same way as also in GNOME 3.16 and in other desktop environments. The notifications can be sent via a notification daemon from the command line.

The command is part of the package `libnotify-bin` and is installed by the `*-desktop` meta-packages.

The dependencies are `libc6`, `libglib2.0-0`, `libnotify4`. Run `strace` to see the way of your notification:

```
% strace -e open notify-send foo bar 
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnotify.so.4", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
```

To send your own notification

```
notify-send foo bar
```

From [`man notify-send`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man1/notify-send.1.html):

```
SYNOPSIS
       notify-send [OPTIONS] <summary> [body]

OPTIONS
       -u, --urgency=LEVEL Specifies the urgency level (low, normal,
            critical).

       -t, --expire-time=TIME
            The duration, in milliseconds, for the notification to appear
            on screen.  (Ubuntu's Notify OSD and GNOME Shell both ignore
            this parameter.)

       -i, --icon=ICON[,ICON...]
             Specifies an icon filename or stock icon to display.

       -c, --category=TYPE[,TYPE...]
             Specifies the notification category.

          Help options:

       -?, --help
             Show this help message

       -h, --hint=TYPE:NAME:VALUE
             Specifies basic extra data to pass. Valid types are int,
             double, string and byte.
```

Comment: what about `sudo notify-send foo bar`?

Comment: @acgbox what about it? It should run under the user that has the desktop environment open, I believe

Answer (score 4):

The [following](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lunar/en/man1/zenity.1.html) also works

```
zenity --notification --window-icon=update.png --text "System update necessary!"
```